# Path Continuity and Stochastic Integration

Tags: real-analysis, stochastic-processes, stochastic-integrals

In a book I'm working through there is a proof that $$\int_0^{\tau(\omega)\land t}f(\omega,s)dB_s(\omega) = \int_0^t f(\omega,s)1\{s\le \tau(\omega)\}dB_s(\omega)$$ The proof begins by claiming that $\tau_n = 2^{-n}(\lfloor2^n\tau\rfloor+1)$ is a stopping time converging to $\tau$ with $\tau \ge k2^{-n}$ iff $\tau_n \ge (k+1)2^{-n}$, that $\int_0^{\tau_n\land t}fdB = \int_0^t 1_{(0,\tau_n]}(s)f(s)dB_s$ and that $\int_0^t 1_{(0,\tau_n]}(s)f(s)dB_s \to \int_0^t 1_{(0,\tau]}(s)f(s)dB_s$ in $\mathcal{L}^2$. Then it says that using path continuity on $\int_0^{\tau_n\land t}fdB$ completes the proof.

I have two questions about this. First, I'm unsure about the claim that $\tau_n$ is a stopping time and was wondering how you could prove that it is true. Second is that for the last step, I am unsure of what is meant by applying path continuity, so any explanation of what's going on in that step would be greatly appreciated! Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi for the 1st question observe that $\forall n\geq0, \tau_n\leq \tau$ by definition of $\tau_n$.

It is sufficient to prove that $\{\tau_n\leq t\}\in \mathcal{F}_t$, but $\{\tau_n\leq \tau\}$ so $\{\tau_n\leq t\}\subset \{\tau\leq t\}$ and as the last set is in $\mathcal{F}_t$ ($\tau$ is a stopping time) this in turn shows that $\{\tau_n\leq t\}\in \mathcal{F}_t$ .

For the second question the first $L^2$ argument shows that :

$\int_0^{\tau_n(\omega)\land t}f(\omega,s)dB_s(\omega)\to \int_0^t f(\omega,s)1\{s\le \tau(\omega)\}dB_s(\omega)$

The path continuity argument (of the stochastic integral seen as a process) argument shows that :

$\int_0^{\tau_n(\omega)\land t}f(\omega,s)dB_s(\omega)\to \int_0^{\tau(\omega)\land t}f(\omega,s)dB_s(\omega)$

which allows to conclude that both quantities are the same.

Best regards

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, but I'm still a bit confused on that second part. Could you explain a bit more of what path continuity means in this context and why it implies the limit you specified? I've tried reading the section on path continuity but I'm not getting it.

Comment: @ thorspinkhammer : Hi this means if you look at the process $Y_t=\0^t X_s dB_s$, it is a continuous process (*). As $\tau_n\land t \to \tau\land t$ almost surely, $Y_{\tau_n\land t}\to Y_{\tau\land t}$ is that clearer ? Best regards (*)The awfull truth is that this process has a continuous modification but ushh.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense, thanks!